does not find an image - pyautogui
I tried everything, changed the folder(English, Russian), indicated the exact path through os.path.abspath(file), does not find png photo
import time
import pyautogui
import os
 
# Функция для проверки наличия изображения на экране
def is_image_on_screen(image_path, region=None, confidence=0.7):
    try:
        # Получаем абсолютный путь к изображению
        script_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        image_path_absolute = os.path.join(script_directory, image_path)
 
        location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image_path, region=region, confidence=confidence)
        return location is not None
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Ошибка при поиске изображения: {e}")
        return False
 
# Подождем некоторое время перед началом работы скрипта
time.sleep(5)
# Проверяем, есть ли реклама на экране
if is_image_on_screen("mark.png"):
    # Кликаем по рекламе
    advert_location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("mark.png")
    advert_center = pyautogui.center(advert_location)
    pyautogui.click(advert_center)
 
# Прокручиваем экран, чтобы найти рекламу 
pyautogui.scroll(100)
 
# Список изображений кнопок закрытия рекламы
close_button_images = ['close.png', 'close2.png', 'close3.png']

# Перебираем изображения и ищем каждую кнопку закрытия рекламы
for close_button_image in close_button_images:
    if is_image_on_screen(close_button_image):
        # Найдена кнопка закрытия рекламы, кликаем по ней
        close_button_location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(close_button_image)
        close_button_center = pyautogui.center(close_button_location)
        pyautogui.click(close_button_center)
        
pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 's')

ERROR: [ WARN:0@5.244] global loadsave.cpp:248 cv::findDecoder imread_('close3.png'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
Failed to read close3.png because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format

what happens if you copy and paste the exact file path (full path) from the file explorer ?

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

first try code with /full/path/to/close3.png. You could also check if your file doesn't have some spaces in name - you may not see spaces when you display filenames but for system/python it is is different filename and it may not find file. You could also check in what folder you runs code - os.getcwd() (Current Working Directory)

you could also use print() to check what you have in script_directory and what you have in this folder os.listdir(script_directory)

you use pyautogui.locateOnScreen(close_button_image) but you may need full path pyautogui.locateOnScreen( os.path.join(script_directory, close_button_image) ).

Problem is that you use os.path.join(script_directory, ...) inside is_image_on_screen to create fullpath but later you use only filename without path locateOnScreen(image_path, ...) and  locateOnScreen(close_button_image). You should always use image_path_absolute - or you should change folder  os.chdir(script_directory) before you use filename without fillpath
